# How to remove plot backgrounds and grids in Google Colaboratory

Tags: plot, google-colaboratory

When I try to plot some data in Google Colaboratory, it automatically adds some light blueish color and white grids. I want to have a black frame and white background only. Is it possible to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typical `matplotlib` styling options apply in Colab as you'd expect. Here's an example:
https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=1Gd5qmaw-eqoa2jV0HxEjOssE0PYVpEtH

The key bits are:

```
plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor'] = 'white'
plt.grid(c='grey')
```

Answer (score 5):

I just started using Google Colab this week and also find the plots in colab got a certain style. To make it back to the same default style as jupyter notebook just add this line after you import matplotlib:

```
plt.style.use('default')
```

Answer (score 4):

To remove grid, try this:

```
plt.grid(None)
```